# What do square brackets mean in property_path Symfony form option

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've seen in a project that [property-path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) can be used with square brackets like this:

```
foreach ($foo as $i => $object) {
    $builder->add("foo_{$i}", 'checkbox', array(
        'property_path' => "[$i].foo",
    ));
}
```

This seems to associate each field to the object's `foo` property with the given `id`, but I've not found out any documentation about it. Only [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638794/build-a-form-having-a-checkbox-for-each-entity-in-a-doctrine-collection#answer-14653394).
Any idea of what does it mean and where is it documented?

Comment: Check it out I think this is the answer to your question. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Mattia .__. in fact, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Symfony [UPGRADE from 2.0 to 2.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.1.md) says:

> The mapping of property paths to arrays has changed.
>
> Previously, a property path `"street"` mapped to both a field `$street` of a class (or its accessors `getStreet()` and `setStreet()`) and an index `['street']` of an array or an object implementing `\ArrayAccess`.
>
> Now, the property path `"street"` only maps to a class field (or accessors), while the property path `"[street]"` only maps to indices.

Also take a look on Symfony's documentation about [the PropertyAccess component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html).

The purpose of `property_path` is explained in the [FormType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#reference-form-option-property-path) page but I guess you already know what it is used for.

For the code you posted I guess *(I used Symfony forms only once, just scratched its surface)* that for each property `bar` of object `$foo` it creates an `<input type="checkbox" name="foo_bar">`.

When the form is submitted, the `property_path` tells the form to put the value of the checkbox named `foo_bar` into `$data['bar']->foo` where `$data` is the object returned by method `getData()` of the form.

Comment: Perfect! Indeed it also works with `'property_path' => "[foo]"`. The reason of  `'property_path' => "[$i].foo"` is also working is explained here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html#reading-from-arrays

Answer (score -1):

It's a PHP thing.  You can use variables within a string if you add squiggly brackets around it, instead of separating it out of the string.

```
$x = "world";
echo "Hello, {$x}";
// is equivalent to
echo "Hello, " . $x;
```

This is documented [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), just do a find for "curly".

Comment: I meant "square brackets", sorry.