# Generate form from queried collection of entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Using symfony 2.6 and twig : I have answers provided by a lot of users in my database. I want to create a form linsing all of them for a given user, to allow him to edit them.

I get these responses with the following code :

Controller :

```
$responses = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Response')
->findBy(
    array('user' => $usr,
        'response' => 1,
        'response' => 2
    ),
    array('id' => 'ASC')
);

$form = $this->createForm(new ActionType, $responses)->createView();
```

ActionType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('check', 'entity', array(
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Response',
            'property'      => 'id',
            'property_path' => '[id]',
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638794/build-a-form-having-a-checkbox-for-each-entity-in-a-doctrine-collection) does exactly what I want, but I can't get it working. The form generated is way too huge : it takes the whole Response table... Do you have any clue why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you rely solely on doctrine lazy loading it will load *all* your related entities, it's both good and bad like that.

To filter your responses for user fetch your data with QueryBuilder like so:

```
$responses = $queryBuilder->select('u', 'r')
                ->from('YourBundle:User', 'u')
                ->join('u.responses', 'r')
                ->where('u.id = :userId')
                ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('userId', $yourUserEntity->getId())
                ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

As above, specifically selecting the entities you want hydrated avoids a lazy load of all available data.