# Multiple checkboxes form in symfony - How to use var_dump() with entities?

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I am having trouble making my multiple checkboxes list of Messages work. I want to be able to select few entries and delete/or move them to spam folder. I get stuck while trying to `var_dump` (for debugging purposes) content of `data = $form->getData()`, expression `var_dump(data['id'])` Prints like entire codebase of Symfony3 :D (which was for me totally unexpected) I based my code on 
[Build a form having a checkbox for each entity in a doctrine collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638794/build-a-form-having-a-checkbox-for-each-entity-in-a-doctrine-collection) and use Doctrine.
This is the code

```
class MessageEntitySelectByIdentityType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', EntityType::class, array(
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => 'MonoDomainBundle:Message',
  //      'property'      => 'id',
        'property_path' => '[id]', # in square brackets!
        'multiple'      => true,
        'expanded'      => true
    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'      => Message::class,
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
```

}

```
public function mailboxAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MonoDomainBundle:User')->find(1);

$collection = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Message::class)->getMyInbox($user);
$form = $this
    ->createForm(
        \Mono\DomainBundle\Form\MessageEntitySelectByIdentityType::class,
        $collection
    );
$form->add('spam', SubmitType::class);
$form->add('delete', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Trash']);

$form->handleRequest($request);
$this->addFlash('success', 'settings.simplified.general.text.success');

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $data = $form['id']->getData();
    var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using var_dump() on Doctrine entities goes to circular recursion by each relation.

That's why :
Symfony provide a [dump() function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html#the-dump-function).

Comment: that makes sense, when i visited controller action using var_dump server hang out because was running out of memory, thanks for your help :)