# Submit expanded EntityType Field with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, entity

I have used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653394/123594) to create a form for a list of entities with a checkbox on each row:

Form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('sites', EntityType::class, [
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => Site::class,
        'choice_label'  => function($site){
            return '['.$site->getId().']';
        },
        'multiple'      => true,
        'expanded'      => true
    ]);

}
```

Twig:

```
{% for site in sites %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ form_widget(actionform.sites[site.getId]) }}</td>
```

However I can't get submitting the ajax right:

Currently I'm using:

```
$.post(
        '{{ path('site_add_to_upgrade', { 'page': page } ) }}',
            {
              'site_action_form[_token]': '{{ actionform._token.vars.value }}',
              'site_action_form[sites]': $('.itemlist input[name^="site_action_form"]:checked').serialize()
            }
)
```

but this throws an the Error:

```
\Symfony\component\Form\FormError
message: This value is not valid
messageParameters:
    {{ value }}: site_action_form%5Bsites%5D%5B%5D=4
```

How can I submit these checkboxes, so I can loop through them?

Comment: For reference to anyone helping, the URL encoding decoded in the error message is:`site_action_form[sites][]=4`

Comment: I don't think, you have to pass `site_action_form[_token]` manually in ajax. It must have been hidden when `FormType` renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide the work in two parts :
1 -  Make sure the form works when sending it in sync.
2 -  Send your form as is using ajax :

```
$(this).on('submit', '#wrapper_id > form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
         //process with return data
    });
});
```

For the records, this is more an jQuery question than a symfony, or ajax one.

Hope this helps